# Add Ionicon to canvas in ionic 1

Tags: canvas, ionic-framework, ionicons

I am trying to build a seatmap for my ionic 1 app, and I have a function called drawSquare that looks like this:

```
var drawSquare = function(xPos, yPos, width, height) {
    var ctx = scope.canvas.ctx;

    ctx.fillStyle = '#7854AF';
    ctx.font = fontSize + 'px Ionicons';

    ctx.fillText(String.fromCharCode(0xf3a6), xPos, yPos);
};
```

But for some reason it is drawing all the icons as Squares.
[image]

somehow it doesn't recognize the font when rendering, even though the icon font is clearly loaded, because the rest of the page shows icons without any problem.

I would be grateful for help.